# phpMyAdmin - Calculate daily average

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database which shows the temperature in a certain location over time. The values are measured every 10 minutes as shown in the picture. Every location has an own ID called "Stationsnummer" (Station number).

[image]

What i want to do is calculate daily averages. So i need to write a query which calculates a daily average of the column "Temperatur Oberfläche".

With the query:

```
SELECT AVG (`Temperatur Oberfläche [°C]`)
FROM `temperatur oberfläche`
WHERE `Stationsnummer` LIKE '4900180611' AND `Datum` like '1998-11-10'
```

I get the average of one day. But in the end I wanna have something like this as a result:

[image]

Does someone has an idea how it can work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GurV thanks a lot for your help. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GROUP BY for this:

```
select `datum`, avg(`Temperatur Oberfläche [°C]`)
from `temperatur oberfläche`
WHERE `Stationsnummer` = '4900180611' 
group by `datum`;
```

Further if you want to find avg temp for all the stationsnummer for each day, you can include that too, like this:

```
select `Stationsnummer`, `datum`, avg(`Temperatur Oberfläche [°C]`)
from `temperatur oberfläche`
group by `Stationsnummer`, `datum`;
```

Comment: `Stationsnummer LIKE '4900180611' `? is it needed?

Comment: @Rahul yes, if you look at OP's query. The result is taken for a date and a stationnumber, not all stations.

Comment: NO it's not. If you are not using any wild card then you don't need *like* operator. It's that dead simple

Comment: @Rahul Oh you meant - why *like*? That's I fixed some time ago.